# What is the cause for this invalid path issue when trying to run cpp protocol buffer compiler from CMake on Windows 10 and how can I solve it?

Tags: cmake, windows-10, protocol-buffers, android-auto, protobuf-c

I'm trying to build the [aasdk](https://github.com/f1xpl/aasdk) project on a Windows 10 computer. To do this, I am attempting to run the following commands in the root of the git repo directory:

```
mkdir buildDir
cd buildDir
cmake ..\
cmake --build . --config Release
```

The last command is obviously the one that's failing. I get the following output when I run that command:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19041.
-- Found libusb-1.0:
--  - Includes: C:/libusb-master/x64/Release
--  - Libraries: C:/libusb-master/x64/Release/lib/libusb-1.0.lib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/aasdk-development/buildDir
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(200
,5): warning MSB8062: Custom build for item "C:\aasdk-development\buildDir\CMakeFiles\b2b8e2a3c1aae1e014a7c3c3f8aadde7\AVCha
nnelData.pb.h.rule" specifies invalid path "C:\aasdk-development\buildDir\aasdk_proto\protobuf::protoc" as an additional dep
endency. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly. [C:\aasdk-development\buildDir\aasdk_proto\aasdk_proto.vcxpro
j]
...
  Running cpp protocol buffer compiler on C:/aasdk-development/aasdk_proto/AVChannelData.proto
  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(238
,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\aasdk-development\buildDir\CMakeFiles\b2b8e2a3c1aae1e014a7c3c3f8aadde7\AVChannelDat
a.pb.h.rule;...' exited
with code 123. [C:\aasdk-development\buildDir\aasdk_proto\aasdk_proto.vcxproj]
```

Where `...` is the same message repetead for each *.proto file inside `aasdk_proto` directory. From what I can tell, it seems it thinks some paths are invalid. What I can't tell, is which paths and in what way are they invalid.

After the first comment, I decided to check where it gets those paths. Below is the content of the `CMakeLists.txt` for protobuf, found in the `aasdk_proto` directory:

```
include(FindProtobuf)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})

file(GLOB_RECURSE proto_files ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.proto)
protobuf_generate_cpp(proto_sources proto_headers ${proto_files})
add_library(aasdk_proto SHARED ${proto_headers} ${proto_sources})
target_link_libraries(aasdk_proto ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

Of interest is the 5th line which enumerates all the *.proto files in the relevant directory before calling `protobuf_generate_cpp`, the part which I believe to be causing the errors.

Adding `message(STATUS ProtoFiles: ${proto_files})` after line 5 to print the paths yielded correct values, atleast to my eyes:

```
C:/aasdk-development/aasdk_proto/AbsoluteInputEventData.proto;C:/aasdk-development/aasdk_proto/AbsoluteInputEventData.proto;...
```

I replaced the forward slash with a backslash just for giggles, since that's how Windows likes them, but that didn't work.

Comment: `"C:\aasdk-development\buildDir\aasdk_proto\protobuf::protoc"` This doens't look like a correct path!

Comment: I agree, but then again, this could be the normal output of CMake/protobuf for all I know.   Regardless, I don't think I know what to check. See my edit.

Comment: Remove `include(FindProtobuf)`. Scripts like `FindXXX.cmake` should be included only via `find_package`, which you already do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but for anyone still having this problem, I ran into a similar issue while building [CuraEngine](https://github.com/Ultimaker/CuraEngine), and found the cause. In my case, I had to set the path to `protoc.exe` with *both* variables `PROTOC` and `Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE`. (I had only set `PROTOC` and CMake didn't throw any errors.)

I imagine the situation with aasdk must be similar. Some variable (probably `PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE`?) that tells the location of `protoc.exe` must be missing.